# How can I reset all styles to the browser defaults for a specific element?

Tags: css

I'm building a front-end widget which can be embedded on any web page.

I don't want the host page's styles to affect the widget. So, I'd like to reset all styles for `#widget`, and its descendants, *to the browser defaults*.

This is what [`all: revert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) does – but it doesn't have widespread browser support yet. I'm essentially looking for a polyfill for `all: revert`.

(The phrase "to their browser defaults" is important. I know that I can use `all: initial` to reset styles to their *initial* value. But the initial value is not the same thing as the browser's default value.)

I'm familiar with [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and similar resets/boilerplates. Those aren't what I'm looking for. They don't reset *all* styles – only those which are inconsistent between the major browsers' default stylesheets.

For example, say that the host page contains the style `body { font-style: italic }` (unlikely, but possible). Boilerplate-type CSS resets would not correct this: the text in my widget would also be italic.

(Please think carefully before marking this question as a duplicate. There are similar questions on Stack Overflow – but many of them were posted many years ago, when the situation was quite different, or they're asking subtly different questions.)

Thanks!

Comment: Use an iframe to embed the widget.

Comment: Not an acceptable solution for my use case.

Comment: It seems like Shadow DOM may be what you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom

Comment: Please explain why an iframe is not acceptable. Is it personal preference? Or a technological constraint? You said, _"on any web page,"_ which leads me to believe it's not an environmental issue like a CMS.

Comment: For starters, because an iframe can't have a fluid height (without adding JavaScript to the host page).

I'm pursuing the Shadow DOM approach. So far, I think it will work (although it involves a lot of polyfills, and a lot of fiddling with Gulp/Babel to get everything building correctly).

Comment: Maybe offer a bounty on the old questions, to draw attention to them again?

Comment: @EliasZamaria: Eh. I researched several possible ways of achieving this. I basically concluded that it's not possible – at least, not in any remotely practical and cross-browser way. The two best options – such as they are – are (1) an iframe, and (2) manually reset everything in your widget, and then use !important on all of your actual styles. Both are far from ideal, but I couldn't find anything better.